# Is there a phrase for not arguing about taste?

Tags: phrase-requests

In Hebrew there is a phrase that roughly translates:

> On taste and smell there is no point in arguing.

This is of course because both are very subjective.
Is there an English phrase that passes the same sentiment? (That it is senseless to debate tastes).

Comment: “[De gustibus non est disputandum](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/De%20gustibus%20non%20est%20disputandum)” is a phrase well-known to many English speakers, although not quite an English phrase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suitable saying for "different people like/dislike different things"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285803/suitable-saying-for-different-people-like-dislike-different-things)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider:

1. [Every man to his taste](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Every+man+to+his+taste): *Prov.* Everyone likes something different, and you should not condemn people because of what they like. (Can be used to remark that someone's tastes are different from yours, as in the first example.)
2. [There's no accounting for taste](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There+is+no+accounting+for+taste): *Prov.* You cannot blame different people because they like different things, even if you do not understand why they like what they like.
3. [Tastes differ](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tastes+differ): *Prov*. Different people like different things.
4. [One man's meat is another man's poison](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/One+man%27s+meat+is+another+man%27s+poison): *Prov*. Something that one person likes may be distasteful to someone else.
5. [To each their own / Each to their own](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to_each_their_own#English): Every person is entitled to his or her personal preferences and tastes.

There's also a related (but crude) phrase, "Opinions are like assholes. Everyone has one.", which is well known.

Comment: "Opinions are like assholes. Everyone has one." lol

Comment: 'To each his own' seems the best answer here. The other options provide some nice elaboration.

Comment: Is there an unspoken statement after your last example? *"Your* opinion means that you *are* one."

Answer (score 4):

I am reminded of the phrases: "*In matters of taste, there can be no disputes*" or "*There must not be debate concerning tastes*".

Both these phrases are the translation of the Latin saying [de gustibus non est disputandum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_gustibus_non_est_disputandum). It implies that taste is a matter of opinion in which there is no *right* or *wrong*, thus its not subject to be debated.

Comment: This is very enlightening. Thank you. I didn't accept this answer because it is a Latin translation, and not an English phrase. But hey... At least now I know where the Hebrew phrase comes from.

Comment: You are welcome. Correctly said, the phrases are actually translations of the Latin saying and did not originate in the English language. However, your description caused this to immediately spring up in my mind. I am quite happy with you accepting the current answer though.

Answer (score 1):

**That's why they make chocolate and vanilla**

> Used to express the fact that it's OK for people to have varying
> tastes or preferences.
>
> *The over-the-top, campy aesthetic of the film certainly won't be for everyone, but **that's why they make chocolate
> and vanilla.***
>
> [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/that%27s+why+they+make+chocolate+and+vanilla)

---

> Most Internet service providers (ISPs) offer some sort of free trial
> time I would encourage a beginner to take several up on the offer to
> see which one that they like best. There is really no particular ISP
> that is the best; it is a matter of opinion. That's why it's good to
> try several because what your friend likes you may hate. **That's why
> they make chocolate and vanilla**, so you decide.
> [Jay Lurie; *Compuquest* Vol. 1](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Compquest/6CDk-MgZ9jUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22That%27s%20why%20they%20make%20chocolate%20and%20vanilla%22&pg=PA48&printsec=frontcover) (2001)

---

I learned this expression from my dad.

Comment: +1 for sentimental value. I'm also a dad.

Answer (score 1):

How about " Different strokes for different folks"

According to Wikipedia:
It has 1950s US origin, popularized by Muhammad Ali (1966) and later the song Everyday People by Sly Stone (1968).

It actually has a very close meaning to the OP's original hebrew source

Answer (score 0):

It were not best that we should all think alike; it is difference of opinion that makes horse-races.
- Pudd'nhead Wilson's Calendar, 1894